# Answer moved to comment by mod

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, answers, moderation

I joined a community today because I had something unique to add to a question. There already was a decent answer, but mine was talking about points not mentioned in it.

While my answer was a bit short, as I could bring my point across in one sentence, came to the same conclusion as the other answer and gave it credit, it did very much stand at it's own. However a mod seemed to disagree and changed it to a comment while (presumably - it could have been someone else) also giving me a down vote.

It is my understanding that posts that contain new information directly relating to the question and can stand on their own should be posted as answers and not as comments to other answers.

So what should I have done in this case? Should I have commented? Should I have said nothing considering I don't have the reputation?

I realize why I can't write comments with low reputation, however I don't understand why I can't use my reputation from other communities to do it.

So that you can judge for yourself, here's the question in question with my comment attached to the answer, this is not supposed to put blame on the mod. [Did Narendra Modi tweet this?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/38517)

Comment: Are you referring to [this comment](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38517/did-narendra-modi-tweet-this#comment155361_38518)? (You can get permalinks to comments by clicking on their timestamps, by the way.)

Comment: As a note, I don't really think that your comment there is much of an answer. It seems like a direct response to the existing answer. The fact that you refer to the points made directly make it seem very much like a comment. If you truly mean it to be an answer, you need to flesh it out more, particularly on a site like Skeptics.

Comment: Also this appears to be two questions in one. "*I don't understand why I can't use my reputation from other communities to do it.*" is global and more appropriate for this site (MSE), while your specific issue with that question is probably better served by following Catija's advice to post on the Skeptics meta, as community policies do differ (and I know the answer to your question and can tell you it is *relatively* Skeptics-specific, as your comment cannot stand on its own as per Skeptics answer quality standards).

Comment: As a note, when you get to 200 rep on any one community, you will automatically earn 100 rep on every community, which gives you the ability to comment on nearly every post. For information see [What is the association bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the Skeptics.SE, Syzygy. I am sorry your first experience was so confusing.

I recommend having a read of our [Welcome to New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users). It explains some of the ways in which we are different to other forums.

One of the biggest ways we are different is in how we deal with opinions. Other sites (e.g. YouTube, Reddit, Twitter and the comments section on every news article ever) train us to believe that our position on an issue is important, welcome and should be shared in the comments. However, on Skeptics.SE we are not interested in that. What we are interested in is what the *evidence* shows.

Your answer did not contain any evidence. It contained your personal judgement that the image was forged. As such, it wasn't a suitable answer on this site.

What should you have done? I wouldn't even encourage you to post this as a comment. If you could find more references to support the claim that it was a forgery, you might post an answer based on that.

(I hope this isn't seen as an admonishment - this is a common newbie mistake, that I made a few times myself.)

As mentioned by others, regarding the rep from other sites, you can use the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus) to enable you to immediately comment.

More reading:

- [Sorry, but we don't care about your political opinions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/sorry-but-we-dont-care-about-your-political-opinions)

Answer (score 2):

> I realize why I can't write comments with low reputation, however I don't understand why I can't use my reputation from other communities to do it.

[As Catija mentioned](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/answer-moved-to-comment-by-mod#comment12423_3987), you actually can use your rep from other sites for commenting.

Once you hit 200 reputation on a single site, you will get a 100 reputation bonus for every Stack Exchange site. This should give you plenty more than the 50 required for commenting.

For more information, see **[What is the association bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)**

Comment: For some reason, my original answer was deleted when the question was migrated from meta, so I had to retype it from scratch

Comment: It was deleted because of NAA flags ~2-3 minutes prior to the migration. [Timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/296667/timeline) (or [detail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/296668/timeline)).