# Why was my question downvoted?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Skeptics Stack Exchange post: [Why did Biden make a strategic mistake and create a crisis by leaving Afghanistan?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/52203/why-did-biden-make-a-strategic-mistake-and-create-a-crisis-by-leaving-afghanista)

Why was it closed?

Comment: We just simply don't do questions like that, about anyone. Please see the [tour] and [help].

Comment: How this is a question worth downvoting? The original question might have been bad, yet why is asking how to improve also bad? Maybe the question is asked in bad faith, but I can't see it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @pinegulf Check the edit history. Both the question OP is asking about, and this Meta question, were asked in *extremely* bad faith. Oddthinking edited all the bad-faith accusations out before answering.

Comment: @F1Krazy Sorry, how do I do that? It could be that I don't have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: @pinegulf Click where it says "edited Aug 15 at 11:15" and you should be able to see the revision history, it's not locked behind a reputation barrier.

Comment: Thx. This makes more sense.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of helpful guides that explain why this question is off-topic here:

- [tour](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [help center](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help)
- [Welcome to New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users)
- [Sorry, but we don't care about your political opinions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/sorry-but-we-dont-care-about-your-political-opinions)
- [Explanation that motivation questions are off-topic](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/978/23)

Comment: [Note: The reasons for your account suspension were for continued abusive behaviour after being warned. I normally wouldn't publicly comment on such things, but you have not provided a genuine email address, and I fear you are going to attribute it to some conspiracy against you because of political beliefs. That won't help you improve your contributions in the future.]